# How can the size of the notification queue be configured?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, event-notification

The documentation for [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-notify.html) states

> The queue is quite large (8GB in a standard installation) and should be sufficiently sized for almost every use case

Is it possible to configure the size of the queue?  I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation or in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting large payloads through NOTIFY to begin with. It's way more efficient to e.g. just include the primary key in the payload, rather than the complete row (or even multiple rows). But I would guess that you can only change this size by compiling Postgres yourself

Comment: I don't plan to exceed the size in such a fashion, I'm  curious as to how the size might be adjusted.  I agree the term "standard installation" suggests it might be set at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in [async.c](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/commands/async.c;h=4613bd1cfb60667039561c233fa85f2443bcd5f3;hb=7fd89f4d7a51af77175a876613cffb490b9e5df1#l298)

```c
 298 #define QUEUE_PAGESIZE              BLCKSZ
     ...
 300 
 301 /*
     ...
 310  * The most data we can have in the queue at a time is QUEUE_MAX_PAGE/2
 311  * pages, because more than that would confuse slru.c into thinking there
 312  * was a wraparound condition.  With the default BLCKSZ this means there
 313  * can be up to 8GB of queued-and-not-read data.
```

This supports the notion that the queue size is not configurable without changes to the source and recompilation, as [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) [commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291542/how-can-the-size-of-the-notification-queue-be-configured#comment570504_291542).